# Converting Dirichlet Boundary Conditions to Neumann Boundary Conditions for the Laplace Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm solving the Laplace equation on a two dimensional square domain. The problem is defined as:
$$
u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0 \hskip{0.5cm}\text{for} \hskip{0.5cm} 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1
$$
with the following boundary conditions:
$$
u(0,y)= 0, \hskip{0.5cm} u(1,y)= 0, \hskip{0.5cm} u(x,1)= 0, \hskip{0.5cm} u(x,0)= \sin(\pi x)
$$
I'm able to solve this eqations both numerically and analytically, however I'm having trouble with the following: I would like to convert the boundary condition on $u(x,0)$ to an equivalent Neumann boundary condition. I've tried the following:
$$
u_x(x,0) = \pi \cos(\pi x)
$$
However this is not resulting in a satisfactory result. Is my thinking correct?

edit:

The exact solution I get is:
$$
u(x,y)= \sin(\pi x) \cdot \left[ \cosh(\pi y) - \coth(\pi) \cdot \sinh(\pi y) \right]
$$

Edit:

I've got it working now using
$u_y(x,y) = \pi \cosh(\pi) / \sinh(\pi) \sin(\pi x)$ as the Neumann boundary condition.

Thank you for your help,

Jan Willem

Answer (score 0):

Look at a solution $v(x,y)$ of the Neumann problem 
\begin{align*}
v_{xx}+v_{yy}& =0\text{ in the unit square} \\
v_{x}(0,y)=v_{x}(1,y)& =0 \\
v_{y}(x,1)& =0 \\
v_{y}(x,0)& =-\pi \cos \pi x.
\end{align*}
Now obtain a solution $u(x,y)$ of your Dirichlet problem as the curve
integral 
\begin{equation*}
u(x,y)=\int_{\varphi }\left( -v_{y}\mathrm{\,d}x+v_{x}\,\mathrm{d}y\right) ,
\end{equation*}
where $\varphi $ is any curve in the unit square connecting $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)
$. By the Gauss-Green theorem and the heat equation satisfied by $v$, the
value of this integral is independent of the path. For example, 
\begin{equation*}
u(x,y)=-\int_{0}^{x}v_{y}(s,0)\mathrm{\,d}s+\int_{0}^{y}v_{x}(x,t)\,\mathrm{d
}t.
\end{equation*}
From this follows that 
\begin{align*}
u_{x}& =-v_{y} \\
u_{y}& =v_{x},
\end{align*}
and hence 
\begin{equation*}
u_{xx}+u_{yy}=-v_{yx}+v_{xy}=0.
\end{equation*}
Also the Dirichlet boundary values are easily checked.

Comment: I see what you mean. I messed up and got it to work (see my edit). Thanks.

Comment: Interesting that the Cauchy-Riemann equations pop up here, do you have any idea why that is the case?